# Expressing area under polar curve as Fourier coefficients

Tags: integration, fourier-analysis, polar-coordinates

> Let $f$ be a positive continuous function of $2 \pi$. Express the area inside the polar curve $r = f(\theta)$ in terms of the Fourier coefficients for $f$.

We know from freshman calculus that the area under a polar curve is expressed as $A= \int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{1}{2}r^2d\theta$. Furthermore, the Fourier coefficients for $f$ will look like $c_n = \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{0}^{2\pi}re^{-in\theta}d\theta$. So I want to express $A$ in terms of $c_n$. However, I am having a hard time handling the complex exponential as I have very little experience manipulating these sort of objects. Is it simple property manipulation of $e^{-in\theta}$ or is there something deeper that I should be considering here?

Comment: It will be easier to directly substitute the Fourier expansion of $r=f(θ)=\sum c_ne^{inθ}$ into the area integral, and then transform the product of sums  $\sum c_ne^{inθ}\sum c_me^{imθ}$ into a single sum by grouping together terms with the same exponent, see [Convolution theorem for Fourier series coefficients](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution_theorem#Convolution_theorem_for_Fourier_series_coefficients). Finally, integrate the resulting single sum termwise.

Comment: Given that there is an integral of $f^2$ involved and you know that $f$ is real, this is just an application of Parseval's Theorem, which you can prove separately with the hint above.

Comment: So if I know Parseval's Theorem, is it as straightforward as $\frac{1}{\pi}||f||^2 = \sum_{n = -\infty}^{\infty} |c_n|^2$?